# Python: Why does '_' not format properly in Jupyter Notebook strings

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

In Jupyter Notebook When I format a string with an underscore, it is not showing up properly.

For example:

`'help{}'.format('_with_underscores_')`

returns `'help with underscores '`

and the underscores are still missing if I print the string.
Oddly though the underscore is still there.

If I set `a = 'help{}'.format('_with_underscores_')`
then `a[-1]=='_'` returns `True`
Using python directly from terminal returns the underscores perfectly.

So two questions:

- how can I make my underscores show up properly in Jupyter Notebook?
- can I rely on them always being there?

---

Thanks to those who have commented: This problem arose on Firefox running on Centos. Following the comments below I tried to reproduce it on Safari and on Chrome and its fine - so I'm going to stop worrying - thanks again for the help.

---

Comment: Works as expected here.

Comment: `'help{}'.format('_with_underscores_')` outputs `'help_with_underscores_'` in jupyter with a python 3.6 kernel.

Comment: I think the problem is related to your web browser, and the answer of second question is "yes".